# MySQL Get score of each user in each category

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i have the following tables:

```
users (id)

question_categories(id)

questions(id, category)

answers(id, user, question, score)
```

My problem is to get the total score of each user in each category in order to filter them based on the score in each category.

I expect a result table like (user, score_cat_1, score_cat_2, ...). I tried this option by building the table from PHP to add each category score column, but there is a join subquery I have to run on each category column I want to add. Something like

```
SELECT u.id, SUM(cat1.score) AS score_cat_1, ...
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT score, category, user
     FROM answers a
     JOIN questions q ON a.question=q.id AND q.category=1
) AS cat1 ON u.id=cat1.user
...
```

So I fear a performance issue with the size of that table and the number of categories. Is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried this ? http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Comment: @ColourDalnet Yes, that is what i came into after some readings. I plan to use the prepare statement of mysql, and build the query dynamically in mysql. I will give a try.

Comment: @GáborBakos No, it definitely does not. This is nowhere near Code Revieww material. Please check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers